# Find User in Laravel by Username

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

So typically if you have access to the id of a user in laravel you can run User::find($id), however say you don't have access to the user's id and only their username. Is there a better way than using DB::query to locate the user?

This is my current solution and was wondering if someone possibly knew a better way.

```
$user_id = DB::table('users')->where('username', $user_input)->first()->id;
```

Comment: you can do whereUsername($user_input) instead of where, it's not really much difference though

Comment: Perhaps use `->value('id');`? as well instead of `->first()->id`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, even better using the model. just like this

```
User::where('username','John') -> first();
// or use like 
User::where('username','like','%John%') -> first();
User::where('username','like','%John') -> first();
User::where('username','like','Jo%') -> first();
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'even better'. There is a performance hit on using model queries as opposed to DB queries - so some could argue that OP's usage is a good route. Depends on the usage.

Answer (score 6):

It depends. If a user is logged in you can have any information you want by:

```
$field = Auth::user()->field;
```

But if they are not logged in and you just want their user_id you can use:

```
$user_id = User::select('id')->where('username', $username)->first();
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand using Auth::user()->blah, but I needed to find a user by their specified username without them being logged in.  Thank you for providing an alternate to the code I had been using. I just wanted to check whether there was a better or more efficient alternative. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$user_id = DB::table('users')->where('username', $user_input)->first();
```

without "->id"

check here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Comment: @Adamnick, did you get an answer that worked for you?