# Get user in Laravel 5.2 by username

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a user by username and return his profile page.

The route is defined like this:

```
 Route::get('user/{slug}', 'UserController@getUserByName');
```

and in my `UserController`, I've defined `getUserByName` like this

```
public function getUserByName($slug)
{
    $user_id = User::where('username', $slug)->first()->id;
    return view('users.user', compact('user_id'));
}
```

However I get an error `No query results for model [App\User]`

I've tried almost all the solutions suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147247/find-user-in-laravel-by-username) , I'm still getting the same error for all the answers.

The Users table's schema is defined like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

What should be the correct way of defining the query?

I'm using phpMysql

**Edit:**

`users.user` blade template is defined like this:

```
@extends('layouts.users')

@section('title'){{$user->username}} profile @stop

@section('container')
   @include('users._rightnav')
        <div class="alert alert-info text-center clearfix">
            User details
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            Username:  {{$user->username}}
            Email:     {{$user->email}}
        </div>
@stop
```

Comment: Can you show us your blade view code?

Comment: are you sure you have a user by that username ? dump the $slug to see if it's actually been passed correctly .

Comment: You need to pass $user instead of $user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit,

You should write your code as below.

**In Controller,**

```
public function getUserByName($slug){      
    $user = User::where('username', $slug)->first();        
    return view('users.user', compact('user'));
}
```

**In View(blade file),**

```
@extends('layouts.users')

@section('title')

{{$user ? $user->username : 'No user found'}} profile 

@stop

@section('container')
   @include('users._rightnav')
        <div class="alert alert-info text-center clearfix">
            User details
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            Username:  {{$user ? $user->username : 'No user found'}}
            Email:     {{$user ? $user->email : 'No user found'}}
        </div>
@stop
```

**Note:-** Always check query result first before accessing it's property to avoid '***trying to get property of non-object***' error.

Comment: You are wrong, look over `compact` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

Answer (score 2):

You should always check query result before accessing to its properties

```
public function getUserByName($slug)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $slug)->first();
    $user_id = $user ? $user->id : null;
    return view('users.user', compact('user_id'));
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error `No query results for model [App\User]` . Where should I put the function? In `UserController` or `User` model ?

Comment: What function? Can we see your `users.user` blade template?

Comment: Edited. Check out the template above. It's pretty neat

Comment: I did mistake in the query. Solved now.