# User::where returns null collection

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a profile section of my website where I can take the username from the URL and query my database for that username. Either the other questions I have read are out of date or I am doing something wrong. I run the following Eloquent command in php artisan tinker

```
App\User::where('name', 'Tom');
```

However, when I run this command in my terminal, I get a blank eloquent collectioion. I am confused. Here is where I got my information for the where query: [Find User in Laravel by Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147247/find-user-in-laravel-by-username)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) to return an actual row you need to use the `first` method, or to return several rows the `get` method.

This code would return the first instance of `name='Tom'`:

```
App\User::where('name', 'Tom')->first();
```

If you're trying to get all the rows equal to Tom, then you would do this:

```
App\User::where('name', 'Tom')->get();
```

Comment: ahh, thanks. i should have checked the documentation myself. Thanks, but I should look harder next time.